# Paragraphs and table not found in a Word Document (open XML)

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have created simple open XML document (.dotx) using MS Word. The file contains simple text and one table. I am trying to replace few custom placeholders in the text with the new text, however the below snippet cannot find any `Paragraph` nor `Table` in the document. I have tried to create several new .dotx files and also tried different variations of the document type i.e. `.dotx` and `(Strict Open XML) .docx` using MS Word but the issue still remains.

```
   using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(templatePath, true))
        {

            var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>(); // <-- always empty
            var tables = body.Descendants<Table>(); // <-- always empty

            foreach (Table t in tables)
            {
                t.Append(new TableRow(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("test"))))));
            }

            foreach (var para in paras)
            {
                foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                {
                    foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                    {
                        if (text.Text.Contains("###name###"))
                        {
                            text.Text = text.Text.Replace("###name###", "Sample");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.SaveAs(resultPath);
        }
```

Funny enough if I use the below snippet from MS docs it does work, however It is not clear how to add additional rows to the table. Therefore, I would prefer to use the first method istead. Any idea what could be the issue with the file or the above code?

```
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(templatePath, true))
        {
            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Regex regexText = new Regex("###name###");
            docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "My Text!");

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your document with Editor like MS Word it could add some containers, which wrap your paragraph, I'd suggest you check xml which generated. To do that, you can simply rename `.docx` to `.zip` and open that archive.

Inside you will found files like that
[image]

You will need to open `word/document.xml` with any text editor and see, if `<w:p>` there and it is direct child of `<w:body>`. If it is not direct, use `descendants` method.

```
var paras = body.Descendants<Paragraph>(); // <-- always empty
```

`Elements` finds only direct children.

`Descendants` finds children at any level.

Also, most common issue is wrong namespace, as `Paragraph` exists in the amny of namespaces of `OpenXml`, you have to use `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;`

Comment: hi I just checked this and it seems that `-<w:body>` `<w:p> ` is direct child
since i in the testing mode i can use any Editor .. can you propose one?

Comment: I mean the Notepad, VS Code or Atom

Comment: I have opened the file succesffully and the sequence seems to be correct as stated above. I have also tried to re-create the file with WordPad and it seem that the issue persists..

Comment: I don't see problem in your code then. Can you check your templatePath is it valid, and your file in the correct place? And what is `resultPath` in your code?

Comment: yes file is valid as i see it is loaded via 'using' statement ... also i use same path later on in the code .. so no problem there.

Comment: looks like in the second code you update original file from templatePath, and in the first one you save it in another location `resultPath`

Comment: both codes in the end will do the same, which is (a) replace some text in the template and (b) copy it to another location. However, I am stack at the first bit which is text replacement.

Comment: The problem can comes from your `using` on the top of file. Paragraph exists in different namespaces of `openxml`, you should use `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;` do you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225595/discussion-between-jim-and-siarheik).